# WordPress pages are not published due to External database connection with WPDB class

Tags: plugin-development, pages

I am developing a **wordpress plugin** that connects to external database,
fetch data, and displays it on metabox below page/post editor.
I used following code:

```
<?php
/** MySQL hostname */
define('EXT_DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** MySQL database name */
define('EXT_DB_NAME', 'trader');

/** MySQL database username */
define('EXT_DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('EXT_DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySql table prefix */
define('TABLE_PREFIX','sc_');

$new_wpdb=new WPDB(EXT_DB_USER, EXT_DB_PASSWORD, EXT_DB_NAME, EXT_DB_HOST);

?>
```

Saved this file as *wp-db-config.php*

Included this file in constructor of main plugin class and
I used AJAX for fetching data.
The data is shown in metabax below editor in both posts and page.
I got success in adding, getting, deleting, updating data.

The main problem arise is that I cant update or create new post and page.
I googled this problem but I didnt get solution. Please help me out of this problem. its very urgent for me.

Comment: Do you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)? What is the point of `$new_db='';`?

Comment: it's just a variable ignore it..

Comment: I know it is a variable. Why is it there? Why is it initialized when you actually use `$new_wpdb` for your new database connection? The more important question was about the debugging information.

Answer (score 2):

After establishing the connection to "your" DB and doing all the required work you need to reestablish the connection to the DB wordpress uses. Just keeping the object around is not good enough.

Comment: I have my code at http://pastebin.com/wcZB2PGH and detail problem at https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1npytyQkR_c6i9BqrIMLKFX9daK3pO-_X6GKJoYRKbN0/edit?usp=sharing. Please help me out of these.

Comment: You asked a question and got an answer, if the answer is not clear enough you can ask for clarification.

Comment: i didn't get any solution yet. I just used destructor that contains code to connect to wordpress database. but still the same problem exists. I have provided the code as well as the image for better clarification of my problem.

Comment: please provide me the solution with code example.